# How to create a Total row in a Matrix table PHP

Tags: php, arrays, ms-access

I'm trying to create a new row in my matrix table for the total value in each column.
Expected Output:

```
 Day  | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | ... | Dec |
 1    | 3.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 5.0 | 1.0 | ... | 1.0 |
 2    | 6.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 6.0 | 1.0 | ... | 1.0 |
 3    | 3.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 4.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | ... | 0.0 |
 4    | 4.0 | 1.0 | 0.0 | 3.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | ... | 0.0 |
 5    | 3.0 | 1.0 | 0.0 | 2.0 | 0.0 | 1.0 | ... | 0.0 |
 6    | 0.0 | 0.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 0.0 | 1.0 | ... | 0.0 |
 7    | 0.0 | 0.0 | 1.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | ... | 2.0 |
 8    | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 2.0 | 1.0 | 0.0 | ... | 1.0 |
 9    | 1.0 | 0.0 | 1.0 | 3.0 | 1.0 | 0.0 | ... | 0.0 |
 10   | 4.0 | 0.0 | 1.0 | 3.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | ... | 1.0 |
...
 31   | 0.0 | 1.0 | 0.0 | 4.0 | 0.0 | 8.0 | ... | 0.0 |
Total |20.0 |12.0 |10.0 |11.0 |10.0 |30.0 | ... |10.0 |
```

Here's the code:

```
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs)){
$Station = $row['StationCode'];
$Year = $row['Year'];
$Day = $row['Day'];
$Month = $row['Month'];
$data[$Day][$Month] = $row['D_Rainfall'];
$montharray[] = $row['Month'];
}
<table class="table table bordered table-condensed">
<thead>         
    <tr>
    <th>Day</th>
$montharray = array_unique($montharray);
        foreach($montharray as $name){
echo '<th>' . $name . '</th>'; //Month
        }                   
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '</thead>';
        echo '<tbody>';           
        foreach($data as $day=>$rainfall){
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<th>'. $day .'</th>'; //Days
                    foreach($montharray as $name){
                        $D_rainfall = isset($rainfall[$name]) ? $rainfall[$name] : '-';
                        echo '<td>' . $D_rainfall . '</td>'; //Rainfall value per day/month
                    }
            echo '</tr>';
            }
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th>Total</th>';
            echo '<td> Sum? </td>'; // What do I need to do here?
            }
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '</tbody>';
    echo '</table>';
```

I also need to find the average value in each column, but i guess if I found out how to do this, I could handle the average row.

Comment: You can best create a separate query in Ms Access to calculate those totals (or use a union query to append the totals to the bottom of the query). If you want a more thorough answer, you need to provide your current table structure, and the query fetching this data.

Comment: `SELECT StationCode, Year, Month, Day, D_Rainfall
FROM DailyRainfall
WHERE StationCode = 1 AND Year = 2016
ORDER BY Year DESC , Month ASC , Day ASC`  

Thats all there is in the table, i just read somewhere to avoid using `*` in queries. Assuming the user prompted stationcode = 1 and year 2016.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code :

```
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs)){
$Station = $row['StationCode'];
$Year = $row['Year'];
$Day = $row['Day'];
$Month = $row['Month'];
$data[$Day][$Month] = $row['D_Rainfall'];
$montharray[] = $row['Month'];
$sumArray=  [];
}
<table class="table table bordered table-condensed">
<thead>         
    <tr>
    <th>Day</th>
$montharray = array_unique($montharray);
        foreach($montharray as $name){
            $sumArray[$name] = 0;
echo '<th>' . $name . '</th>'; //Month
        }                   
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '</thead>';
        echo '<tbody>';           
        foreach($data as $day=>$rainfall){
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<th>'. $day .'</th>'; //Days

                    foreach($montharray as $name){
                        $sumArray[$name] += isset($rainfall[$name]) ? $rainfall[$name] : 0 

                        $D_rainfall = isset($rainfall[$name]) ? $rainfall[$name] : '-';
                        echo '<td>' . $D_rainfall . '</td>'; //Rainfall value per day/month
                    }
            echo '</tr>';
            }
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th>Total</th>';
        foreach($montharray as $name){

            echo '<td>'. $sumArray[$name].'</td>'; // What do I need to do here?
            }
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '</tbody>';
    echo '</table>';
```

Comment: I'd like to ask what if I want to find the average and min/max too? Im trying to do it using array within the `foreach` but its displaying the results for the whole year: 
`$maxArray[] = isset($rainfall[$name]) ? $rainfall[$name] : 0;`
  and
`foreach($montharray as $name){
 echo '<td>'. max($maxArray) .'</td>';
}`

For now this is what I came up for finding the max